# Ruby StringIO for concurrent reading and writing

Tags: ruby, string, buffer

I'm looking for some [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html)-similar class, that allows me to write and read concurrently from different parts of my program.
From one part of the program I want to write (append) characters to the buffer, from another part I want to read them.

The problem with StringIO is the following:

```
buffer = StringIO.new
buffer.write "Foobar"      # Write to the buffer
buffer.rewind              # Move the pointer to beginning
buffer.getc                #=> F
buffer.getc                #=> o

buffer.write("something")  # Write more to the buffer
buffer.string              #=> Fosomething
buffer.getc                #=> nil
buffer.pos                 #=> 11
```

Whenever I write to the buffer, it is written to the current position. Aterwards the position is moved to the last written characters.

What I need is a StringBuffer with two seperate positions for reading and writing, instead of only one. Does something like this exist in ruby or do I have to do in on my own?

Comment: Mutating a shared variable across threads is non-deterministic in MRI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Queue.html).  If you do not need thread safety, then a simple array might be fine too.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because it might be a good way for others, even tough it didn't work for me. I'm doing an interpreter and sometimes the interpreter expects more input. In that case I just ask the user for more input. Queues didn't work, because my read-thread will die if the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is single-threaded, try coroutines, aka blocks.

```rb
def do_stuff
  yield rand(100)
end

100.times do
  do_stuff { |response| puts response }
end
```